# How to make rank with a function c#

Tags: c#, rank

I have this code:

```
private int[] rank(decimal[] NetFlow)
{
    int[] result = new int[NetFlow.Length];
    int temp;
    int[] result2 = new int[NetFlow.Length];
    for (int x = 0; x < NetFlow.Length; x++)
    {
        result[x] = x;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < NetFlow.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i; j < NetFlow.Length; j++)
        {
            if (NetFlow[result[i]] < NetFlow[result[j]])
            {
                temp = result[i];
                result[i] = result[j];
                result[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int y = 0; y < NetFlow.Length; y++)
    {
        result2[result[y]] = y + 1;
    }
    return result2;
}
```

The following code will save the result of rank into a database:

```
int[] rankResult = rank(NetFlow);
string show = "";

string period = cmbperiodAwal.Text;
string year = numericYear.Value.ToString();
for (int ii = 0; ii < rankResult.Length; ii++)
{

    string Numb = dataGridView1[dataGridView1.Columns["Numb"].Index, ii].Value.ToString();
    RC.rankUpdate(rankResult[ii], Numb, period, year);
    show = show + "\n" + rankResult[ii].ToString() + "  " + Numb + " " + period + " " + year;
}
```

The problem is, I want the rank to be equal when two numbers are equal. This is my input-data from NetFlow:

> 4.1
>
> 3.3
>
> 5.5
>
> 3.3
>
> 7.4

And I want get output like this:

> 3
>
> 4
>
> 2
>
> 4
>
> 1

Afterwards I want to update the values to the database so there is one column for the rank.

Comment: Please clarify what you're trying to do. Also copy in your code so we can see it and play with it.

Comment: @DanielA.Thompson done

Comment: What do you mean by rank? Please provide a sample input, your algorithm's current output for that input, and what you want the output to be.

Comment: I have data in array. All of data save into Netflow (name of the variable). For example i have 5 data, data in Netflow are: 4.1, 3.3, 5.5, 2.1, 7.4. And i want get output like this:  3, 4, 2, 5, 1

Comment: Please edit those into the original question after your code sample, along with what the current output is for that input array.

Comment: @DanielA.Thompson done sir

Comment: So by rank you simply mean you want to sort the numbers and get the 1/2/3...th greatest, right? So rank 3 means the 3rd highest number?

Comment: @HimBromBeere yeah, you know what i mean

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you can use a simple Linq-query to do this:

```
var ranks = NetFlow.OrderByDescending(x => x)
    .GroupBy(x => x)
    .Select((x, i) => new { Numbers = x.ToList(), Rank = i + 1});
```

This will first order your input from greatest to lowest and then group it to also handle duplicates. Finally you select all the numbers together with their index within the list of groups.

This gives you a list of groups where evry group contains the (equal) numbers as a list and the rank.

Comment: Its a decent start, but doesn't address duplicate values.  You can see in the OP's sample output that both `3.3` values have a rank of `4`.

Comment: @SamAxe Indeed, I missed this step. Updated

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the most efficient way, but quickly and out of my head:

```
var groups = netflow.OrderByDescending(x => x).GroupBy(x => x).Select(x => x.Key).ToArray();
var rank = netflow.Select(x => Array.IndexOf(groups, x)+1);
```

[Check it out here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HbVk82)

The result is:

> 3 4 2 4 1

Comment: How i can save the result into database sir?

Comment: @Stev that depends on your database, how you are accessing it, etc. But that'd need details that would more likely go on a different question.

Comment: @Stev Saving to DB is a completely new question.